# Remove Prolog from MacOS

Tags: macos

I have a MacBookPro with macOS Sierra v.10.12.1.  I downloaded gprolog from this [link](http://www.gprolog.org/#download) and installed this using MacPorts.

Now, given that Prolog does not work like I wanted, I decided to remove it, but I don't know how.

I tried to remove it using Homebrew, running:

```
:~ dario$ brew remove gprolog
```

but this gives me

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gprolog
```

If I run `gprolog` command in terminal, it gives me

```
-bash: gprolog: command not found
```

The only way I have to run gprolog is writing `gprolog` in Spotlight and clicking on gprolog's icon.
I also tried to run `which gprolog` and `whereis gprolog`, without any results.

How can I uninstall gprolog from my Mac?

Comment: I am an old Linux user, so I'm awkward on mac

Comment: *"installs GNU Prolog in /opt/local/ and /opt/local/bin"* (from the download link) – you should look there.

Comment: Could I remove the folders containing gprolog without negative effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you installed it using MacPorts but you tried to uninstall it using Homebrew? Homebrew has no knowledge that you installed it using MacPorts. Use MacPorts to uninstall:

```
port uninstall gprolog
```

If that's not the case, you can manually remove the following files instead:

[image]

Comment: I uninstall it removing all these folders and my Mac is now clean!